# Why won't my dark oak saplings grow when placed in a 2x2 square?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Dark Oak Saplings placed in a 2 x 2 square and with 6 blocks of space around them on all sides. Yet, they still won't grow even after I dumped four full stacks of Bone Meal on them. Can anyone provide any advice on how to grow them properly?

Comment: Do they have light? And a lot of space above?

Answer (score 3):

First off, nothing neighboring the saplings - no tall grass, no flowers, no torches, no snow layers. The entire 4x4 area must be clear. Then enough room for the tree to grow, plus 1 block of margin. Some light - torches 2 blocks away suffice in case there's no daylight.

Leaving tall grass or snow is the most common error when growing 4x4 trees.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would first try it on creative world then if not try different grass block and if that doesnt work then test other trees like regular oak or spruce exc. besides these try picking them up and then replant